# Error: Missing \endgroup inserted (dmath)

Tags: errors, grouping

I have the problem with the error shown in the following screenshot. I cannot figure out what the problem is as this identical syntax has worked in other files...
Thanks in advance for your help!

[image]

Comment: Don't show screenshots - we can't test this. Show a small complete example.

Comment: The `$` sign in `$120,000` needs to become a `\$`, i.e. you need `\$120,000`. However, as @UlrikeFischer says, you should post a complete example so that others can test what they are suggesting. (Of course, you are not supposed to typeset the stuff in the way you do with all the `\\ ` and so on.)

Comment: note that badness10000 that you show is the _maximum_ measure of tex's measure of  badness (caused by `\\ \\ ` here)

Comment: Thank you! Do you mean that I shouldn't typeset the way I do (with the \\) only when posting the example or in general?

Comment: You should almost never end a line with two backslashes. Probably you will get many suggestions to improve your code once you upload a complete minimal example (no screen shot).